# Main account for our exchange

Tags: accounts, xlm

We need to have main account in order to let our customers to deposit into it. But since stellar does not let you generate account without getting funds into it from an existing account, we do not get how to make this main account.
We found some answers telling to go to an exchanges that support create account but we would like to make it on our own and not depend on other exchanges or other 3rd party.
So in short, how can we make real account that will serve us as main account? How can we fund it without having existing account on stellar?

Answer (score 1):

1. Buy XLM from whatever exchange works best for you (check that it supports creating an account when sending to a new keypair, if it doesn't then send it to a wallet that does).
2. Generate a Keypair using [Stellar Lab](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/) or some other officially endorsed tool (keep the **secret key** secure and private).
3. Send your XLM to the **public key** of this account (the wallet/exchange should perform a [Create Account](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.createAccount) operation if the keys are new).

I know for sure that [PapayaBot](https://papayabot.com/) on Telegram will create the account when sending to new keys. I'm sure most other good wallets will too.

In short, you can create keys all day long, it's not until you perform a createAccount operation from an existing account that those keys exist (and have value) on the ledger.

Comment: Lets assume that our exchange is the only one exists ... how can we create account on stellar? that is why i asked it without depending on exchange.

Comment: There is no way to do it without a third party. It's like asking how to create a bank account without dealing with banks, financial organizations, or other people. You won't posses a, say, dollar unless someone give it to you. Therefore, you'll need at least 2 XLM to begin with. If dealing with exchanges is such a big problem for you, DM me your public key, I'll send you 2 XLM.