# how to transfer XLM from licensed Exchanges to inactive account?

Tags: payments, exchanges, lumens, new-developer

I need to transfer XLM to my own (self created) Account. I have the account generated by Stellar Account Viewer ( https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/#!/ ) but it seems that account is currently inactive, so there is no way to transfer any XLM to fund it.

Do you know the Exchange which allows to transfer XLM to inactive account generated by Stellar Account Viewer?

Comment: Use https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#?network=public and in transaction builder tab use Create Account operation. or alternatively use https://lobstr.co/ they will fund you minimum required balance for stellar account.

Comment: laboratory is not a quite good option because _Create Account_ operation in _transaction builder_ tab requires the existing and already funded source account ... but yes, you and Richard are right - using [lobstr.co](https://lobstr.co) or any other wallet as the intermediary account I can achieve the goal - thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PapayaBot](https://papayabot.com/) is a Telegram based bot/wallet that will automatically create the account if it doesn't already exist.

You could forward it there first and then onto your own account. I'm sure most other decent wallets do this as well.

See the [createAccount](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.createAccount) operation.

Also, see [this answer](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/2119/1229) for more info.